# How to use readonly property in date picker in flutter

Tags: flutter, date, datepicker, dependencies, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to use the read only property in date picker but unable to do so.

```
Future<void> SelectSpouseDOB(BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(1970),
      lastDate: DateTime(2101),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
            // Customize the color scheme
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
              primary: Color.fromARGB(
                  255, 250, 174, 52), // Header and selected day color
              onPrimary: Color.fromARGB(255, 247, 244,
                  244), // Header text and selected day text color
              surface: const Color.fromARGB(
                  255, 171, 2, 58), // Calendar background color
              onSurface: Color.fromARGB(255, 12, 12, 12), // Calendar text color
            ),
            dialogBackgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(
                255, 231, 142, 142), // Background color of the dialog
          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
    );

if (pickedDate != null) {
  // Format the pickedDate as "dd,MM,yyyy"
  final formattedDate = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(pickedDate);
  spousedateOfBirthController.text = formattedDate;
 }
}
```

I want to add the readOnly property there. The user should note be able to write any alphabets within

Comment: please format your question properly first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question needs to be properly formatted,

I assume that your `spousedateOfBirthController` is attached to `TextField`, you need to set the property `readOnly` to that `TextField` so your code becomes:

```
TextField(
  controller: spousedateOfBirthController,
  readOnly: true,
),
```

you can use the attribute `onTap` to open your date picker pop up
or wrap the `TextField` in a `GestureDetector` & `AbsorbPointer` as follows:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: (){
    //open your popup
  },
  child: AbsorbPointer(
    child: TextField(
      controller: spousedateOfBirthController,
      readOnly: true,
    ),
  ),
);
```